# Was Earth governed by Starways Congress?

Tags: enders-game

We know that there were some planets - collectively referred to as "Associated Planet(s)" - that were not (fully) governed by Starways Congress.

**However, I am not sure if it's ever explicitly stated whether Earth itself is governed by Starways Congress. Is there any proof of yes or no?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of the events in Xenocide, a thousand years after the death of Peter "Starways Congress once again united all of humankind under one government." - Chapter 2.  So at least at this point in the saga Earth must be governed by Starways Congress.